# remove the selected item from the Table. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, checkbox, http-delete

I need to click on the button to delete the line with the selected checkbox.
I don't know how to use the filter method. I read the documentation, but there is little information there. help me correct the code

```
 class Table extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            droplets: [],
            allSelected: false,
            isChecked: false
          }
          this.toggleSelectAll = this.toggleSelectAll.bind(this);
          this.toggleSelect = this.toggleSelect.bind(this);
          this.handleChecked = this.handleChecked.bind(this);
          **this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);**
        }
        async componentDidMount() {
          const res = await fetch('http://api.npoint.io/324f4ca2cdd639760638');
          const droplets = await res.json();
          this.setState({ 'droplets': droplets })
        }
        
        toggleSelect(dropletToToggle) {
          this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
          this.setState((prevState) => {
            const newDroplets = prevState.droplets.map((dplt) => {
              if (dplt === dropletToToggle) {
                return { ...dplt, checked: !dplt.checked };
              }
              return dplt;
            });
      
            return {
              ...prevState,
              droplets: newDroplets,
              allSelected: newDroplets.every((d) => !!d.checked)
            };
          });
        }
      
        
        toggleSelectAll() {
          this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
          this.setState((prevState) => {
            const toggle = !prevState.allSelected;
            const newDroplets = prevState.droplets.map((x) => ({
              ...x,
              checked: toggle
            }));
            
            return {
              ...prevState,
              droplets: newDroplets,
              allSelected: toggle
            };
          });
        }
        handleChecked () {
          this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
        }
       
    
        **handleDelete = isChecked => {
          this.setState(state => {
            const { droplets } = state;
            const filteredDroplets = droplets.filter(item => item.id !== isChecked);
            return {
              droplets: filteredDroplets
            };
          });
        };**
    
        render() {
          
          return (
            <div className="body">
              <div className="title">Таблица пользователей</div>
              <table className="panel">
                <Tablehead
                  toggleSelectAll={this.toggleSelectAll}
                  allSelected={this.state.allSelected}
                />
                <tbody className="row">
                  <TableBody
                    droplets={this.state.droplets}
                    toggleSelect={this.toggleSelect}
                  />
                </tbody>
              </table>
              **<button className="button" onClick = {this.handleDelete} >Удалить выбранные</button>**
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
```

the second file in which the item to delete

```
const TableBody = ({ droplets, toggleSelect}) => {

  return (
    <>
      {droplets.map((droplet, item) => (
        <tr className={s.area} key={item.id} > 
          <td>
            <Checkbox
              handleClick={() => toggleSelect(droplet)}
              isChecked={!!droplet.checked}
            />
          </td>
          <td>{droplet.num}</td>
          <td>{droplet.first_name + " " + droplet.last_name}</td>
          <td>{date_form(droplet.date_of_birth)}</td>
          <td>{height_form(droplet.height)}</td>
          <td>{weight_form(droplet.weight)}</td>
          <td>{salary_form(droplet.salary)}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="submit" className={s.button}>
              <Edit />
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="submit" className={s.button}>
              <Trash />
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-butterfly-0s4ff?file=/src/Table.jsx

Comment: TypeError
Failed to fetch. can you fix your sandbox?

Comment: I do not know why the error is, in the program everything works locally, but not here (
Copied in full, double-checked everything

Comment: just saw it again. you need https not http in your fetch command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have altered your sandbox and added some functionality in order to delete the rows.

The comparison is based on full name but you can change it to whatever fits your needs.

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-silence-i51wz

Answer (score 0):

On your `handleDelete` function your filter condition seems wrong

Currently you have:

```
// Filters all droplets that have an id different to the value of isChecked.
const filteredDroplets = droplets.filter(item => item.id !== isChecked);
```

And it should be

```
// Returns all the droplets that are not checked
// Meaning that all the checked items are dropped from the array
const filteredDroplets = droplets.filter(item => !item.isChecked);
```

Comment: this is not enough, it still does not delete (something else I am missing